# New tab graphic design inspiration for Firefox

Tags: firefox, graphic-design, plug-in

I'm looking for an extension that would give me graphic design inspiration in each new tab. (It could be one design, it could be several -- that doesn't matter to me much. But it should be current.)

There's an extension for Chrome that does this called Muzli, but it's not available for Firefox. Is there something similar available for Firefox?

Comment: I know there used to be "Dribbble New Tab", but, unfortunately, that's not available for the latest version of Firefox.